# csv data file exported from a sitecore form is only display in one column

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a sitecore form like this: [image: sitecore-form]

I submitted some data for it and when I click export data from this form, the exported file is display in only one column like this below:
[image]

How can I export those data to separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the `Data` tab and select `Text to columns` under `Data tools`. Then select delimited and hit `Next`. Then select `Semicolon` (instead of Comma which is depicted in below picture as in your case you need semicolon) as the delimiter and hit `Finish`.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose using semicolon ";" as columns separator during import. Then all your data will be divided on separate columns.

Comment: I can not find "using semicolon" option anywhere in export data pop up. Do you mean choosing it during import the exported file to List Manager?

Comment: I mean that when you import CSV file into Excel(or other similar app), there should be an option to select different column separator. You need to chose the right one: ";".

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you for this answer.